# Why title icon doesn't show on phones?

Tags: html, icons

I'd like to display an icon in the title bar of a website.

I've tried this:

```
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="icon.png" />
</head>
```

When I open the website on my laptop the icon shows in the title bar. But when I open the website on my phone the icon doesn't show.

Comment: Please tell us what browser you are using (on your phone) and if it is updated to the latest version.

Comment: I have Safari 12.1 on my phone

Comment: I have also downloaded Chrome on my phone and it still doesn’t show the icon (although on laptop it shows it well when I use chrome)

Comment: I've checked with Safari on my iPhone. I don't get an icon in the title bar on any site. Seems normal. With Chrome I only get an icon in the tab view.